# Capitalize Option in JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a JQM page with `select` element:

```
<select>
    ...
</select>
```

I tried to capitalize its options with css:

```
select{
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

I also added in my css:

```
select option{
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

Capitalization works in desktop web browser like Firefox and Chrome but NOT in mobile web browsers like dolphin and also in android webview. How can I make it work in mobile web browsers?

Comment: Is it a classic select or a jQM one?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about classic select element which is using native android display to show option elements? If you do then you can't capitalize it, it is using option text to show it in android native select look, it will not take css formatting,

In case you are talking about custom jQm select elements this will fix it: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/p3SHm/

CSS:

```
fieldset .ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-checkbox label span span.ui-btn-text {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.ui-select div span span.ui-btn-text span {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

select option{
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

**EDIT:**

What you can do is use javascript to capitalize every word, use it in pagebeforeshow event (or any other event in which your text will be changed before page is shown). Look at my example on top to see how.

```
$('option').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\w+/g, function(w){return w[0].toUpperCase() + w.slice(1).toLowerCase();}));
});
```